# Executing multiple sql files in a bash for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, sqlplus

I'm trying to run the following lines of code in bash to run multiple files on a database.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ${arrIN}; do
    echo "Executing ${file}..";
    sqlplus ${db_user}/${db_password}@${db_host}:1521/${db_sid} @${file};
done
```

For some reason, it will only execute the first file on the database, but won't keep executing them. When I check how many files are in arrIn it prints two, so I know there are multiple files. When I run this:

```
file1=${arrIN[0]}
file2=${arrIN[1]}    
sqlplus ${db_user}/${db_password}@${db_host}:1521/${db_sid} @${file1}
sqlplus ${db_user}/${db_password}@${db_host}:1521/${db_sid} @${file2}
```

It executes both files as expected. I would like to acomplish this in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("0000" "1111")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

- you need `[@]` to loop on all the items in the array.
- without `[@]`, it just loops on the first item, like you experienced.

Comment: You forgot to  double quote `"${arr[@]}"`

Comment: Indeed, fixed, thanks.